# Why does Miller approximation method give the wrong result here?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, impedance

Does anyone know why using Miller approximation method to calculate the input impedance gives the wrong result here?
The right answer is `1/gm`.
I know how to use small signal model and calculate input impedance from that. However, for this question I'm trying to use Miller approximation method convert the feedback resistor Zf into two grounded resistors Z1 and Z2.

[image]

Comment: 1) you need to draw the **small signal equivalent circuit** and analyse that 2) In your drawing there's a Z1, why? Also there's Z2, why? Z1 and Z2 are not in the question's circuit. 3) Explain why you're staring with A = -gm * r0, what are you trying to achieve with that? It looks like you use a solution that applies to a different circuit and question.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I know how to use small signal model and calculate input impedance from that. However, for this question I'm trying to use Miller approximation method convert the feedback resistor Zf into two grounded resistors Z1 and Z2. Z2 is not related to input impedance so I didn't write its formula out.

Comment: So why haven't you accepted any of the answers below? At least one of them addressed your problem correctly.

Comment: @MituRaj I usually waited for sometime to get more answers.  The current answers are great though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake was in the original expression for the voltage gain (which you called \$A\$). The voltage gain in Miller's Theorem is the voltage gain of the circuit *including the effects of the feedback impedance*.

Miller's Theorem is valid when the output voltage is proportional to the input voltage with some constant of proportionality that I will call \$K\$ for consistency with the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_theorem) on Miller's Theorem. We don't yet know what \$K\$ is, but we solve for it self-consistently using the re-drawn circuit with \$Z_1\$ and \$Z_2\$, which depend upon \$K\$. The small-signal voltage at the drain for a given change in the drain current is determined by \$Z_2\$ because of the (presumably) high output impedance of the current source and of \$r_o\$.

It is therefore easy to see that \$K = -g_mZ_2\$. According to Miller's Theorem, \$Z_2 = \frac{Z_f}{1-1/K}\$. Plug this expression for \$Z_2\$ into the expression for \$K\$ and solve for \$K\$:

$$K=-g_m\frac{Z_f}{1-1/K}$$
$$K(1-1/K) = -g_mZ_f$$
$$K = 1-g_mZ_f$$

The input impedance is determined entirely by \$Z_1\$, since the transistor has extremely high input impedance. Therefore \$Z_{eq} = Z_1\$, which according to Miller's Theorem, is \$\frac{Z_f}{1-K}\$. Thus,

$$Z_{eq} = \frac{Z_f}{1-K} = \frac{Z_f}{g_mZ_f} = 1/g_m$$

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_theorem#Explanation):

> The Miller theorem implies that an impedance element is supplied by
> two arbitrary (not necessarily dependent) voltage sources that are
> **connected in series through the common ground**.

(The emphasis is mine).

As there is a current source in the drain branch of your circuit and therefore no two voltage sources that are "connected in series through the common ground", you have two options for applying the Miller theorem: either to replace the current source with a voltage source that has a high internal resistance \$R_D\$ or to add the load to your circuit. Choosing to replace the current source with an equivalent voltage source (well, almost equivalent, but with very high internal resistance) and applying the Miller theorem, we arrive at the expression for the input impedance:
$$
Z_{eq} = {\frac {Z_f + (r_o||R_D)} {1 + g_m(r_o||R_D)}}
$$
Applying the test question condition "Assume Zf and 1/gm << ro" we arrive at the "correct" answer to your multiple-choice test question
$$
Z_{eq} = {\frac {1} {g_m}}
$$
.

**EDIT**

The weakness of applying the Miller theorem in this way is that you need to convert the current source into an equivalent voltage source with a very big internal resistance and then to take the limit of the input impedance with the internal resistance tending to infinity.

As we have current sources in this circuit (the first one is sourcing the current into the transistor and the second, the dependent current source (\$g_m\$) of the transistor, sinks this current), we can try and use [the dual of the Miller theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_theorem#Dual_Miller_theorem_(for_currents)), which replaces the feedback resistor branch by the two branches conducting the referred currents, with impedances respectively equal to \$(1 + α)Z\$ and \$(1 + α)Z/α\$, where \$α = I_2/I_1\$.

To do this, first we draw the equivalent **small-signal** circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frx72J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

KCL gives \$I_2 + I_1 = 0\$, so \$α = -1\$, and we arrive at the same problem that we experience when we use the Miller theorem for voltages. Again, we can resolve the problem here, for example, by entering a finite output resistance of the transistor. But have a look at the circuit: the current \$I_2\$ is defined by the transistor transconductance \$g_m\$ only, \$I_2 = g_m V_{sig}\$, the current \$I_2\$ (and, consequently,  \$I_1\$) does not depend on \$Z_f\$, and the input impedance is

$$
Z_{eq} = -V_{sig}/I_1 = V_{sig}/I_2 = 1/g_m
$$.

No need to replace the feedback resistor with two resistors \$Z_1\$ and \$Z_2\$ and apply the Miller theorem, neither basic nor dual, to this elementary circuit. Although, if you want to, do not fall victim of the logical fallacy of circular reasoning: first you have to make sure that the Miller theorem is applicable. The "correct" value obtained with circular reasoning is not a proof that the theorem is applicable.

P.S. Dear electronics.SE posters, please do a favor, correct typos in the *Dual Miller theorem (for currents)* section of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I don't quite get it. In the small signal mode, the ideal current souce is removed and we can use Vo which is the voltage at drain node of the mos in reference to ground as the second voltage that you mentioned. So both of input and output voltages have the same ground.

Comment: `You can try and consider a closed path via FET's channel, but it does not help in applying the Miller approximation.` Why can't you do that? 
Also from wikipedia link  they just call one node is `V1` and the other node is `K*V1` without showing the external connections from these nodes. So to me it looks very similar to our circuit here.

Comment: It seems I understand the source of your confusion, see edit to the answer.

Comment: After all, no need to overstrain and use the Miller theorem here: the \$Z_{eq}\$ independence of  \$Z_{f}\$ in this circyuit is easily seen by inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the way you are doing it is correct.

In \$A = -g_m r_o\$, \$r_o\$ is the impedance seen at the collector.  It is the impedance of the load in parallel with the output impedance of the transistor.  In this case it is the output impedance of the transistor \$r_o\$ (you get confused when you use the same letter for two things), \$Z_f\$, and the impedance of the current source \$\infty\$ in parallel.  You get \$A = - g_m Z_f\$.  Plug it in and you get \$Z_{eq} = 1 / g_m\$.

Comment: ro is the output impedance of the mos transistor not the ideal current source

Comment: I thought \$r_o\$ was the combined impedance at the output from your work.  Don't use one letter for two things.  Edited.

Comment: if Zf and ro are in parallel, how can you eliminate Zf when the question specifically says Zf << ro ?

Comment: @MituRaj \$Z_f\$ and the output impedance of the transistor are in parallel, and \$Z_f\$ is much less than the output impedance of the transistor, so the output impedance of the transistor is ignored and the result is \$Z_f\$.

Comment: You still have problem: if you plug them you will get: (Zf/1+gmZf). You cannot approximate 1+gmZf to gmZf. Because in the question, Zf << ro and 1 << gmro.